# How to change bootstrap tour arrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tour

I use bootstrap tour but i dont no how to change the arrow to top.

Anyone can tech me to change the arrow to top?

As per screenshot below.

[image]

This is script for bootstrap tour.

```
var tour = new Tour({
    placement: "top",
    storage: false,
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#revision",
    title: "TEST",
    content: "TEST. . . "
  }
]});

tour.init();
tour.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

change your div class to `popover tour-tour fade bottom in`,change your placement `top` to `bottom`

Comment: Please expand you answer and add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the 'placement' property like that:

```
steps: [
{
    element: "#revision",
    title: "TEST",
    content: "TEST. . . "
    placement: top
}
```

]

Comment: if i want to hide the arrow icon what can i do?

Answer (score -1):

This div gets created `<div class="arrow"></div>` try editing the CSS on that class in the bootstrap.css file.